# Does requestAnimationFrame with arguments require to be called in a specific way?

Tags: javascript, html, requestanimationframe

I have the following almost identical code that uses `requestAnimationFrame`

The first function works perfectly and the histogram is accurately drawn. However, for the second function, I'm trying to pass arguments to `drawHistogram` and make it generic however this doesn't seem to work.

```
function drawHistogram1() {
    let data = roi?.data;
    chartContext.clearRect(0, 0, chartCanvas.width, chartCanvas.height);
    // Create an array to store the frequency of each intensity value
    histogram = new Array(256).fill(0);

    for (let i = 0; i < data?.length; i+=4) {
        const intensity = data[i];
        histogram[intensity]++;
    }

    // Find the maximum frequency
    let maxFrequency = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        maxFrequency = Math.max(maxFrequency, histogram[i]);
    }

    // Draw the histogram bars
    for (let i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        let height = (histogram[i] / maxFrequency) * chartCanvas.height
        if (histogram[i] === 1) height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);; //Show something on the graph
        chartContext.fillStyle = `rgb(0, 0, 255)`;
        chartContext.fillRect(i * (chartCanvas.width / 256),chartCanvas.height - height, chartCanvas.width / 256, height);    
    }

    let totalPixels = histogram.reduce((sum, count) => sum + count);
    let pixelsAboveThreshold = histogram.slice(threshold + 1).reduce((sum, count) => sum + count);
    let percentageAboveThreshold = (pixelsAboveThreshold / totalPixels) * 100;
    pat.innerHTML = `${percentageAboveThreshold}%`;

    requestAnimationFrame(drawHistogram1);
}

requestAnimationFrame(drawHistogram1);
```

```
function drawHistogram(data, chartContext) {
    chartContext.clearRect(0, 0, chartCanvas.width, chartCanvas.height);
    // Create an array to store the frequency of each intensity value
    let histogram = new Array(256).fill(0);

    for (let i = 0; i < data?.length; i+=4) {
        const intensity = data[i];
        histogram[intensity]++;
    }

    // Find the maximum frequency
    let maxFrequency = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        maxFrequency = Math.max(maxFrequency, histogram[i]);
    }

    // Draw the histogram bars
    for (let i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        let height = (histogram[i] / maxFrequency) * chartCanvas.height
        if (histogram[i] === 1) height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);; //Show something on the graph
        chartContext.fillStyle = `rgb(0, 0, 255)`;
        chartContext.fillRect(i * (chartCanvas.width / 256),chartCanvas.height - height, chartCanvas.width / 256, height);    
    }

    let totalPixels = histogram.reduce((sum, count) => sum + count);
    let pixelsAboveThreshold = histogram.slice(threshold + 1).reduce((sum, count) => sum + count);
    let percentageAboveThreshold = (pixelsAboveThreshold / totalPixels) * 100;
    pat.innerHTML = `${percentageAboveThreshold}%`;

    requestAnimationFrame(() => drawHistogram(data, chartContext));
}
requestAnimationFrame(() => drawHistogram(roi?.data, chartContext));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your nested call to `requestAnimationFrame()` is passing the same data that it received, so it doesn't get the updated value of `roi.data` each time.

Instead of passing `row.data` to the function, pass `roi`. Then if something is updating that object, you'll extract the current value of `data`.

```
function drawHistogram(roi, chartContext) {
    let data = roi?.data;
    chartContext.clearRect(0, 0, chartCanvas.width, chartCanvas.height);
    // Create an array to store the frequency of each intensity value
    let histogram = new Array(256).fill(0);

    for (let i = 0; i < data?.length; i+=4) {
        const intensity = data[i];
        histogram[intensity]++;
    }

    // Find the maximum frequency
    let maxFrequency = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        maxFrequency = Math.max(maxFrequency, histogram[i]);
    }

    // Draw the histogram bars
    for (let i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        let height = (histogram[i] / maxFrequency) * chartCanvas.height
        if (histogram[i] === 1) height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);; //Show something on the graph
        chartContext.fillStyle = `rgb(0, 0, 255)`;
        chartContext.fillRect(i * (chartCanvas.width / 256),chartCanvas.height - height, chartCanvas.width / 256, height);    
    }

    let totalPixels = histogram.reduce((sum, count) => sum + count);
    let pixelsAboveThreshold = histogram.slice(threshold + 1).reduce((sum, count) => sum + count);
    let percentageAboveThreshold = (pixelsAboveThreshold / totalPixels) * 100;
    pat.innerHTML = `${percentageAboveThreshold}%`;

    requestAnimationFrame(() => drawHistogram(roi, chartContext));
}
requestAnimationFrame(() => drawHistogram(roi, chartContext));
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar but from your explanation this too shouldn't work since the `roi` is also always the same. I've tested this and still it doesn't display

Comment: I assumed `roi` was an object and something is periodically doing `row.data = something;`. If you're reassigning `roi` itself, then I don't think what you want is possible, because you can't pass variables by reference.

Comment: `roi (region of intrest)` is dynamic and it changes once I select a region.

Comment: Then you can't make this generic as you want. You need a modifiable object to pass as the generic parameter.